# Add another variable to a javascript dictionary definition on parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, google-analytics

This Google Analytics code works before:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {'id':'12345', 'name':'Chocolate Bar', 'price':1.50, 'category':'Snacks', 'quantity':1});
```

But then, I have this field somewhere in the page:

```
<input id="ProductQty" name="ProductQty" type="text">
```

So, I update the code like this to send the quantity entered on the input along to the Google Analytics server:

```
var qty = $('#ProductQty').val();
ga('ec:addProduct', {'id':'12345', 'name':'Chocolate Bar', 'price':1.50, 'category':'Snacks', 'quantity':qty});
```

But I got error on my firebug that says:

```
SyntaxError: Expression expected, got ','
```

With arrow pointing on the ':' of the `:qty});`.

What's wrong? How can I do this correctly? I know this maybe has a simple answer and there's ton of answers out there, but I just can't find the answer because I don't know how I should write my search query on google correctly for this problem. You can see that from the lousy and confusing title of this question. I've searched for quite some time now but can't find what I'm looking for. Not even close. Please help. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Thank you for the quick correction. Yes, it was a grave mistake of mine to use the `value()` function. Now, I have changed the `value()` to `val()`, but unfortunately the original problem still persist when I tried to run the code again.

**EDIT 2:** When I tried to run these code on console, here are the results:

```
$('#ProductQty').val()
-->"1"
qty
--> ReferenceError: Qty is not defined
```

How it could be?

Comment: `var qty = $('#ProductQty').val();`

Comment: what does `console.log(qty);` (after you assign it of course) show

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added the console result.